# MySQL Join Query Position from Order

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution to get a row based on certain parameters but then also append that rows position from the ordered query.

So we look for a row like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `SomeName`='UniqueName' 
ORDER BY `SomeFloat` DESC
```

This will get all of the rows I require, but then I'd also like to JOIN the position that this row exists in from that query, as if there are 3 records above that, which `SomeFloat` is higher than I'd like 4 to be returned, is this possible or do I simply need to run a second query?

My second query currently:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `SomeFloat` > ( SELECT `SomeFloat` 
                      FROM `table` 
                      WHERE `SomeFloat` = 1635
                     )
```

So I just want to JOIN the second query as a final column for the initial query to save processing (unless this is actually negligible?)
Of course 1635 is just an example value.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

For example:

The first command would search this table, and order the result by `SomeFloat`

```
UniqueID   UniqueName   SomeFloat   SomeText
       1          Bob        1.02      Lorem
       2         John       12.41      Ipsum
       3        Sarah        7.19     Lipsum
       4      Michael      123.45     Dorelo
```

Assuming we searched for `John` the second query would result in 1, since there is only 1 result higher (Michael's). If we searched for `Bob` then the result here would be 3 since the other 3 are higher.

The end result I would like is for a single query to return this, where `RowsAbove` would be generated by the second query.

```
UniqueID   UniqueName   SomeFloat   SomeText    RowsAbove
       2         John       12.41      Ipsum            1
```

Comment: Create column Write a common table expression creating a `row_number() over partition by (NULL order by SomeFloat) as RN` and then select from it using your  and your count then would be that RN-1

Comment: I'm not sure in your example how "Somefloat" is sorted... it's not numeric, it's not alphabetic... how is that sort working?

Comment: Now why position 1 souldn't it still be position 2 since Michael has a higher SomeFloat?

Comment: Yes that is true, my apologies, I used a horrible name there. Let me change, as Position would actually be the number of rows that are higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- using a Common Table Expression (CTE)  It's like an inline view but pulled out of inline for readability think of it as "Step 1" before your main query that stages data the way you need, in this case adding a row_number.
- we generate a dataset CTE, which is all your data assigning a row number ordered by float descending.  We do this so everything is assigned a sequential number before any records are removed via a where clause.
- then we query the CTE for the unique name and it returns the RowNumber -1 as "position" or "rows above" or whatever it needs to be named.
- since we assigned RowNumber to each record in descending order RN-1 would always be the number of rows with a higher float than the unique name selected.

UNTESTED:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT UniqueID, UniqueName,   SomeFloat,   SomeText
                  , row_number() over (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY SomeFloat DESC) as RN  
--or              , row_number() over (ORDER BY SomeFloat DESC) as RN  

             FROM table A)

SELECT UniqueID, UniqueName, SomeFloat, SomeText, RN-1 as Position
FROM CTE
WHERE UniqueName = 'John'
```

The CTE should give us this result:

```
UniqueID   UniqueName   SomeFloat   SomeText RN
       4      Michael      123.45     Dorelo 1
       2         John       12.41      Ipsum 2
       3        Sarah        7.19     Lipsum 3
       1          Bob        1.02      Lorem 4
```

and when we limit by John and subtract 1 from RN we get

```
       2         John       12.41      Ipsum 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Turns out I didn't need the comment you added, so removed that but needed the trailing closing parenthesis. Thank you very much! I am having trouble upvoting due to low reputation but will ensure it gets selected when I can!

Comment: Not a problem.  So long as you understand what it's doing and why I"m happy !  I can't remember if mySQL requires a `partition by` in the window function so I included it but you may be able to get away with just `row_number() over (ORDER BY SomeFloat DESC)`.    Window functions (aka Analytic Functions) are powerful features enabling you to perform otherwise complex activities in simple methods.

Comment: Tested that out of curiosity, I can still get the same result without using `PARTITION BY null` - again many thanks.